# Loading CSRF token on rails with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf

I've decided to implement my Rails site with only a single page load, and do everything else via AJAX. The problem is that the CSRF token which is generated in `meta` is invalidated once used to submit a signup or signin form. How can I update it without reloading the page?

Comment: what's wrong with manipulating the `META` tags using the `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: If I use that same one pre and post signup, it rejects the CSRF token. I'm wondering how to update the token without a full page reload.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that rails invalidates the CSRF meta token after every single request (or post or whatever) (if it didn't, frameworks like backbone.js would have a tough time :).

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7fb99e5743d88c04357e09960d112376428a6faa/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L100

You are probably making a request BEFORE the request you think is the *invalid* one without the correct token and thus rails deletes your session and subsequent requests are marked as invalid even if they pass the previously-correct token.

Comment: Right so if I want to make multiple requests (form submissions) without refreshing the page, what would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use beforeSend like below in your ajax call for put, post methods.

 `$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
     url: your url,
     data: data
 });`

Answer (score 0):

in each ajax request :

add to data :

authenticity_token: '<%= form_authenticity_token %>'